# Percentage calculation not working for my php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

First of all, I know that percentage calculation is something frequently asked in this forum, and I have read most of them to solve my percentage calculation problem, but look like it's not working well. I have been referring to this

- [Percentage calculation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288126/percentage-calculation-in-php)
- [Return percentage in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951312/how-can-i-return-a-percentage-in-php)
- [Using PHP/MySql to calculate percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182535/using-php-mysql-to-calculate-percentages)

  and many more sites that I have been visiting including W3SSchool. I am really a beginner in PHP programming and is still learning in order to improve, below is my source code

Form code:

```html
<center><form action="" method="post">
<div>
<?php if ($id != '') { ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<p>ID: <?php echo $id; ?></p>
<?php } ?>


<p><strong>Tarikh: *</strong> 
<input type="text"  style="text-transform:uppercase" name="date" value=" <?php echo $date; ?>"/><br/></p>
<p><strong>Di bawah 60 Minit&nbsp;: *</strong> <input type="text" name="casesolved_u"
value="<?php echo $casesolved_u; ?>"/><br/></p>
<p><strong>Jumlah kes : *</strong> <input type="text" name="casesolved_a"
value="<?php echo $casesolved_a; ?>"/></p>
<p><strong> Peratusan : </strong> <input type="text" name="percentage"
value="<?php echo ($percentage, 2); ?>"/></p>
<p>* required</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
</form></center>
```

AND here is my insert new data code

```html
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// get the form data
$date = strtoupper($_POST['date']);
$casesolved_u = htmlentities($_POST['casesolved_u'], ENT_QUOTES);
$casesolved_a = htmlentities($_POST['casesolved_a'], ENT_QUOTES);
$percentage = htmlentities($_POST['percentage'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check all fields are filled
if ($date == '' || $casesolved_u == '' ||$casesolved_a == '' || $percentage == '')
{
// if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage, $error);
}
else
{
// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt= $mysqli->prepare ("INSERT emergency (date, casesolved_u, casesolved_a, percentage) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"))

{
// calculate percentage
$casesolved_u = $row ['casesolved_u'];
$casesolved_a = $row ['casesolved_a'];
$percentage = ($casesolved_u/$casesolved_a)* 100;
echo ($percentage,2);

$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$date, $casesolved_u, $casesolved_a, $percentage);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
// show an error if the query has an error
else
{
echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}

// redirec the user
header("Location: view.php");
}
```

Before this, I do the calculation for the percentage manually in order to store the information in the database, but right now, I want to make the system to try calculate it by it's own, but I failed. Hope there's anyone can help me and I'm sorry again for asking repeating questions since I really don't find the solutions that working for me. Thank you and sorry again.

edit:
Here is what I have in my database right now, so for December, I wish to do the calculation automatically and no more manual calculation.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide examples of inputs and the correct output?

Comment: example: casesolved_u = 20, casesolved_a = 22 , percentage = 90.90, but this one, I do the calculation manually where casesolved_u represent cases solved under the given time and casesolved_a is the total cases

Comment: $percentage = ($casesolved_u / $casesolved_a) * 100; Your current calculations look wrong to me...

Comment: I think your manuall calculation also wrong.
<?php
$casesolved_u = 19;
$casesolved_a = 20;
$percentage = ($casesolved_u / $casesolved_a) * 100;  // 95%

Comment: the data that I insert into the table above was just an example to test whether my add, edit, delete forms were working or not.

Answer (score 0):

The tota number of items is 100%.

If the total number of items were 57 that would be the 100%.
So each unit (each 1 case) can be represented as 100% / 57 = 1,754%

From here you can calculate the percentage for any number of units between 0 and 57.

For example 11 cases would be 11 * 1,754% = 19,29%

In the same way 57 cases are 57 * 1,754% = 99,98% (100%)

**Regarding the code:**

These two variables which are first read from $_POST are overwritten with `$row` which is not declared anywhere. And then they are used to calculate the percentage.

$casesolved_u = $row ['casesolved_u'];
$casesolved_a = $row ['casesolved_a'];

If the calculation should be done with the input from $_POST, remove those two lines, convert those string variables to numbers, and then do the calcualtion.

Comment: Perhaps I  missunderstood your question. I thought you had troubble to understand how to calculate a percentage.

Comment: No, I do understand that I should do casesolved_u/casesolved_a * 100, but in order to put it into the form, I can't seem to find the right way.

Comment: If you manage to do the calculation which is the prloblem you have to put that number in the form? What is it you are not being able to accomplish?

Comment: The problem I faced right now is, that I can't seem to make the system calculate the output manually and they didn't even store the information I put into the form. The percentage should pops up on the percentage field but it's not happening which is why I am so confused right now.

Comment: Regarding the program: I don't see you converting the string parameters to numbers, and the $row variable doesn't seem to be assigend anywhere. If  it should refer to a database row, I don't see any query executed at the time the variable is read.

Comment: Oh, can you point me which part should I add then? Cause I don't really see it.